# Waterfall chart with Plotly - Update Traces

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I'm creating a waterfall plot for three categories, as shown in below code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig=go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Waterfall(
    x = [["Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", 
          "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2",
          "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3" 
          ],
        ["Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         "Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         "Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         ] 
    ],
    measure = ["absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total",
                "absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total",
                "absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total"
                ],
    y = [
        1693,-296,1501,-897,-27,-45,532,
        1439.05,-251.6,1275.85,-762.44,-22.95,-38.25,452.2,
        1134.31,-198.32,1005.67,-600.99,-18.09,-30.150,356.44
         ]
))
```

The code returns this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDf2g.png

What I want to do next is to edit color of 'Gross Income' items to green, so only EBTIDA would present a different layout.
I tried so with:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_color="LightSeaGreen",selector=dict(x='Gross Income'))
```

It doesn't work, though. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: I have tried a number of things based on the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/waterfall-charts/#setting-marker-size-and-color) in the reference, but it seems that you cannot change only the starting point with an increase/decrease and a total.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult because for waterfall charts in plotly, the marker colors are assigned based on whether they are [increasing, decreasing or total](https://plotly.com/python/waterfall-charts/#setting-marker-size-and-color) and cannot be assigned colors based on their category.

However, with a very ugly hack, we can make the plot appear to have the desired color in the "gross income" category. We can plot the gross income bars separately for all three categories, assigning them the same value, and classifying them as "relative" so that we can use the argument `increasing = {"marker":{"color":"lightseagreen"}}` to make them all `lightseagreen`. Note: this only works because they all happen to be positive values.

Then, because we have to add each overlapping gross income as a separate trace, we will need to [offset](https://plotly.com/python/reference/waterfall/#waterfall-offset) each of these bars to ensure they overlap the bars from your original waterfall figure. I just used trial and error to figure out that `offset=-0.4` looks approximately correct. Since these additional bars are purely visual, I also disabled their hover info and prevented them from appearing in the legend.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig=go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Waterfall(
    x = [["Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", 
          "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2",
          "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3" 
          ],
        ["Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         "Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         "Gross Income", "Taxes", "Net Revenue", "CPV", "Variable Expenses", "Recurrent Capex", "EBITDA",
         ] 
    ],
    measure = ["absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total",
                "absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total",
                "absolute", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "relative", "total"
                ],
    y = [
        1693,-296,1501,-897,-27,-45,532,
        1439.05,-251.6,1275.85,-762.44,-22.95,-38.25,452.2,
        1134.31,-198.32,1005.67,-600.99,-18.09,-30.150,356.44
         ]
))

## add the gross income bars in each category
for category, value in zip(["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"], [1693,-1439.05,1134.31]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Waterfall(
        x = [[category],["Gross Income"]],
        measure = ["relative"],
        y = [value],
        increasing = {"marker":{"color":"lightseagreen"}},
        offset=-0.4,
        connector={"visible":False},
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo='skip',
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]